# Heroku App is not seeing enviornment variables for Node JS Application

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, heroku-toolbelt

All of the config variables are set but when I do a console.log(process.env) all I get back is an empty object. Any Idea as to what is causing this?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yea u need to configure them seperately on the dashboard of the heroku application. Take a look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars